# How do I get this model to predict the multi label classification value?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, multilabel-classification

How do I get this model to predict the multi label classification value based on train input and test input?  There are 3 classifications, which are good, bad, and ugly.  train_input is a dictionary that holds the train dataset. test_input is a variable that holds the value of 241.43 which a value of 'good', 'bad', or 'ugly' should be predicted from, in this case probably the predicted value should be 'bad'.

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model

''' 3 multi label classification using deep learning '''

classification_labels_3 = ['good', 'bad', 'ugly']
train_input = {100.23:'good', 234.76:'bad', 500.90:'ugly'}
test_input = 241.43

'''
# Define the keras architecture of your model in 'build_model' and return it. Compilation must be 
done in 'compile_model'.
#   input_shapes  - dictionary of shapes per input as defined train_input dictionary
#   n_classes - For classification, number of target classes
'''

def build_model(input_shapes, n_classes=None):

    '''
    # This input will receive all the train_input features
    # sent to 'main'
    '''

    input_main = Input(shape=input_shapes['main'], name='main')

    x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(input_main)
    x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)

    predictions = Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax')(x)

    '''
    # The 'inputs' parameter of your model must contain the
    # full list of inputs used in the architecture
    '''

    model = Model(inputs=[input_main], outputs=predictions)

    return model

'''
# Compile your model and return it
#   model   - model defined in 'build_model'
'''

def compile_model(model):

    '''  
    # The loss function depends on the type of problem you solve.
    # 'categorical_crossentropy' is appropriate for a multiclass classification.
    '''

    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy')

    return model

'''
#print(build_model(input_shapes=,n_classes=))
#print(compile(source, filename, mode))
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

For predicting multi label class you have to use **softmax** activation function. I can see that you are already using it, so you only have to define the number of classes of it's function:

```
predictions = Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax')(x)
```

As you can see, `n_classes` is defined as a variable of the function `build_model`, so just adjust this variable when you call the function and you will build a model with the outputs you specified.

But first, you have to obtain dataset in a dataframe format. Try do something like that:

```
val=[]
for e in train_input:
    val.append(e)

clas=[]
for e in train_input:
    clas.append(train_input[e])

df=pd.DataFrame(val, columns=["values"])

df["clas"]=clas
```

You will obtain a dataframe like this:

```
    values  clas
0   100.23  good
1   234.76  bad
2   500.90  ugl
```

Comment: Hi, as you can see, your are such a strange format, a dictionary for data.... In my opinion you should transform it to a dataframe. I edited my comment with this code. You are using also an strange format to create your NN... from where you took it, look for documentation. If I were you, change input_main = Input(shape=(1,), name="inputs_preprocessed") and add  x = Reshape((1, 1))(input_main). Finally, you are training a Neuronal network for only one input variable and one output? Too heavy.